# Loopback 4 - How long does the generated token expire? - ex: ToDo

Tags: jwt, token, access-token, loopback4

I am studying the examples that the framework offers

In the To-Do example, it has JWT authentication.

**How long does the generated token expire?**

I didn't see a second or similar parameter, which could help with this

> Link:
> https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/examples/todo-jwt
>
> OR
>
> lb4 example todo-jwt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@loopback/todo-jwt](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/extensions/authentication-jwt) example leverages [@loopback/authentication-jwt](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/extensions/authentication-jwt), which provides configurable defaults.

By default, tokens expire in [21600s](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/extensions/authentication-jwt/src/keys.ts#L14) ([git permalink](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/ab5bb6e0083c2b614f31ab8adfd51f307949c2aa/extensions/authentication-jwt/src/keys.ts#L14)), and refresh tokens expire in [216000s](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/extensions/authentication-jwt/src/keys.ts#L46) ([git permalink](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/ab5bb6e0083c2b614f31ab8adfd51f307949c2aa/extensions/authentication-jwt/src/keys.ts#L46))

Both of these [are configurable](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/extensions/authentication-jwt#extra-configurations) ([git permalink](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/ab5bb6e0083c2b614f31ab8adfd51f307949c2aa/extensions/authentication-jwt#extra-configurations)):

```js
// Inside RestApplication constructor

// for jwt access token expiration
this.bind(TokenServiceBindings.TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN).to("<Expiration Time in sec>");
// for refresh token expiration
this.bind(RefreshTokenServiceBindings.TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN).to("<Expiration Time in sec>");
```

Comment: thanks for the help, and already show you how to set up :)